# Having trouble distinguishing where the block is/if this function has a block

Tags: ruby

I am under the impression that when you write a function, the block is what goes in between `do` and `end`.

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  puts 2 ** i
end
```

So in the function above, would the block part consist of the following?

```
|i| puts 2 ** i
```

Comment: `(1..5).each {}` passes a block to the method, although there's nothing between `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are playing with words. It is a matter of definition. Usually, the block includes the `do` and `end`. The whole:

```
do |i|
  puts 2 ** i
end
```

is the block. But since a block is not an object in Ruby (unlike proc), it does not make much difference whichever you call a block.